# basic sequence in the complexification induces a basic sequence in the underlying real space?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

This should be easy to prove if it is true, but, alas, what SHOULD be easy is not always easy for me ;)

**Conjecture 1.**  Let $X$ be a real Banach space and let $X_\mathbb{C}$ denote its complexification.  Suppose $(x_n\oplus iy_n)$ is a normalized basic sequence in $X_\mathbb{C}$.  Then either $(x_n)$ or $(y_n)$ contains a basic subsequence in $X$.

It *seems* like it should be true, especially since a similar statement holds for seminormalized weakly null sequences.  But maybe there is a counterexample.

Or, if the above is not true, the following weaker conjecture (together with Rosenthal's $\ell_1$ Theorem) would suffice for my purposes.

**Conjecture 2.**  Let $X$ be a real Banach space and let $X_\mathbb{C}$ denote its complexification.  Suppose $(x_n\oplus iy_n)$ is a normalized basic sequence in $X_\mathbb{C}$, which is equivalent to the canonical basis for $\ell_1$.  Then either $(x_n)$ or $(y_n)$ contains a basic subsequence in $X$.

I'm sure this is discussed in some book out there somewhere, so a reference would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Or, wait, does "contain a basic subsequence" only mean that it contains a subsequence that is a basis of the closure of its span?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes I just need a subsequence to be basic, i.e. the Schauder basis of its closed span.